# jquery nth selector in IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

I have a list of elements and need to make some amends to the first element in the list using jquery. I have tried a few methods to target the first item but none of them seem to work in IE7. These are the following methods I've tried...

```
 $(this).eq(1)
 $(this).first()
 $(this:nth-child(1))
```

All of these methods worked in all browsers except IE7, does anyone know of a fix to use for IE7 or a different method that will work in IE7?

Thanks in advance for any help?

Comment: `$(this:nth-child(1))` cannot possibly work in any browser because it's a syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
$(this:first-child)
```

Will get more info from [here](http://www.thebrightlines.com/2010/01/04/alternative-for-nth-of-type-and-nth-child/)

**EDIT**

Sorry for the confusion.
What I was trying to say is to use first-child instead of first()

You can use like this `$('ul li:first-child').css('background-color', 'red');`

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
<ul id="list">
   <li>list item 1</li>
   <li>list item 2</li>
</ul>​

$('#list li').first().css('background-color', 'red');
```

It's working in IE7 http://jsfiddle.net/jur4x/JKBH4/

Comment: Add your code in your answer too. Right now, you answer does not look like a answer itself.

Answer (score 0):

[`.first()`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) is a valid function and will work.

For example:

```
$("li").first(); // will match the first li in the tree
```